# WCF Duplex Service with multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a service that uses duplex requests for calling back to the client application.  I have currently exposed a single endpoint with a NetNamedPipeBinding, this is all working correctly.

When i add a basicHttpBinding i get the follow exception

Contract Requires Duplex, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' dosn't support it

Is it possible to configure the service to allow duplex and basicHttp?

Thanks

Rohan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the contract has call backs then no, you can't use BasicHttpBinding because, as the exception says, it won't support everything your contract needs. If you want to have callbacks over HTTP then you need to use wsDualHttpBinding

Comment: Is there any way to make the callback optional depending on the binding?

Comment: No. The callback is part of the contract, and you cannot partially expose a contact, it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx) of the out-of-the-box binding types.  It has a table that lists whether the binding supports duplex.